# Multi Level import/exports

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an automation testing suite that was done in javascript.  I am in the process of converting the project from javascript to typescript.  In the original project, the structure is as follows:

> helpers
>
> > utilities
> >
> > > salesforce
> > >
> > > > navigation.js
>
> indices
>
> > utilityIndex.js
>
> tests
>
> > myExampleTest.js

navigation.js

```
var files = require('../../../indices/fileIndex.js');
var utility = require('../../../indices/utilityIndex.js);
var pageObjectsSF = require('../../../indices/pageObjectSFIndex.js');

module.exports = {
  "NavigateToAccountFromContact": function (browser) {
    browser
      .click(pageObjectsSF.contact.details.detailsTab.selector, pageObjectsSF.contact.details.detailsTab.type, `Click Details Tab`)
      .click(pageObjectsSF.contact.details.accountName.selector, pageObjectsSF.contact.details.accountName.type, `Click Account Name`);
      utilities.generic.logging();
  }
}
```

Which was converted to: navigation.ts

```
    import * as files from '../../../indices/fileIndex';
    import * as utilities from '../../../indices/utilityIndex';
    import * as pageObjectsSF from '../../../indices/pageObjectSFIndex';
    
    export = {
      "NavigateToAccountFromContact": function (browser) {
        browser
          .click(pageObjectsSF.contact.details.detailsTab.selector, pageObjectsSF.contact.details.detailsTab.type, `Click Details Tab`)
          .click(pageObjectsSF.contact.details.accountName.selector, pageObjectsSF.contact.details.accountName.type, `Click Account Name`);
           utilities.generic.logging();
      }
    }
```

utilityIndex.js

```
exports.navigation = require('../helpers/utilities/salesforce/navigation.ts');
exports.dataValidation = require('../helpers/utilities/salesforce/dataValidation');
exports.search = require('../helpers/utilities/salesforce/search');
exports.generic = require('../helpers/utilities/salesforce/generic');
```

myExampleTest.ts

```
//Declare File Dependencies
var files = require('../../indices/fileIndex.js');
var utilities = require('../../indices/utilityIndex.js');
var query = require('../../indices/queryIndex.js');

module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['Tags'],
  'TestName': function (browser) { 
    //Test Logic Here
  }
};
```

which was converted to: myExampleTest.ts

```
//Declare File Dependencies
import * as files from '../../indices/fileIndex';
import * as utilities from '../../indices/utilityIndex';
import * as query from '../../indices/queryIndex';

export = {

  '@tags': ['Tags'],
  'TestName': function (browser) { 
    //Test Logic Here
  }
};
```

I have not yet converted the utilityIndex to a typescript file, but when I try to run the files I am getting the following error:

```
C:\GitRepos\RegressionTesting\helpers\utilities\salesforce\navigation.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as files from '../../../indices/fileIndex';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:605:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\GitRepos\RegressionTesting\indices\utilityIndex.js:1:84)
```

Originally in utilityIndex.js rather than: `exports.navigation = require('../helpers/utilities/salesforce/navigation.ts');`

I had     `exports.navigation = require('../helpers/utilities/salesforce/navigation');`

but was getting `Error: Cannot find module 'indices/utilityIndex'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that the associated js file to '../helpers/utilities/salesforce/navigation.ts'  did not have the correct path. Once I fixed that it resolved the issue. Thank you

Comment: You can either omit the extension or specify `.js`. `.ts` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run TypeScript files directly with Node.  Either use `tsc` to compile them to JavaScript or use a runtime like [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).